# Can I have a local php.ini for WordPress only?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress set up on Linux in the directory:

`/var/www/html/myblog`

There are three lines I need to add to my php.ini and I when I made these to the php.ini in this directory then everything works as expected:

`/etc`

Is there a way that I can have a php.ini in the blog directory and have wordpress use those values rather than my having to change the /etc/php.ini ?

Note that I did try creating a 3 line php.ini with the changes I need in /var/www/html/myblog but it did not seem to recognize those changes. It only seem to recognize the changes when I add them to the end of the php.ini in the /etc

Comment: This would be specific to the web server that is running PHP. Is it Apache + mod_php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at using [PHP `.user.ini` files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php). The following is from the PHP documentation:

> **.user.ini files**
>
> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a per-directory basis. These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension. If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect.
>
> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache + mod_php, you can use the `PHPINIDir` value to your `VirtualHost` directive.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    PHPINIDir /path/to/your/custom/php.ini
    // ... the rest of your config
</VirtualHost>
```